# Any recommendations for learning the basics of event-driven programming?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events, event-handling

My task for today is to fully understand event-driven programming and how it works. Now there are several ways this can be achieved. The first one is to actually program a basic program that covers the key concepts, and the second approach is to watch a video that explains the key concepts in a way I can understand. Which approach do people recommend?

Does anyone have videos/program demos they found useful and could recommend to me? My major experiences are with ASP.NET MVC, so it would be best if the tutorial were with WebForms ASP.NET.

Comment: I *highly* suggest writing an event-driven program. I've never in my life found a video demo to be very useful. Not to mention watching a video of it is not the same thing as understanding it or being able to do it. I watched a video of open heart surgery once, but I don't think I'm ready to try it myself.

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer, its good advice that I will be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Event-based programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596439)